# observable in the newest version indexeddb not working

Tags: angular, indexeddb

In the newest version of ngx-indexed-db, I see it support observable mechanism. However, I add new data for the indexeddb, my subscribe not handled for this event

```
this.dbService.getAll('people').subscribe((peoples) => {
  console.log(peoples);
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-indexed-db

Can anyone explain to me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide the  NgxIndexedDBModule.forRoot code, without it will be hard to tell you what's wrong

---

Edit

Look at this stackblitz : [Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-indexdb-demo-n4bjwa?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

What i've done :

- Change the Package version : "ngx-indexed-db": "^9.4.2"
- Clear the previous database in the devtool
- The code to show all :

  `this.dbService.getAll<People>('people').subscribe((people) =>  {this.people = people;},(error) => {console.log(error);});`

Comment: @NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, NgxIndexedDBModule.forRoot(dbConfig) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})


with dbConfig is like structure in this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-indexdb-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts